# Accessing Unity Container from View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am trying to use Unity Container in a small WPF-based project. In order to resolve dependencies when my ViewModels create other ViewModels, I need a reference to the container (which is initiated in App_OnStartup). What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Best? Matter of opinion. There is rarely no "best" way to do anything in software development. But if the VM is being instantiated by the container, then it should have a marked dependency on the container itself, so the container will give itself to the view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If things are properly set up - ideally injecting IUnityContainer object in view model constructor should give you reference to all ViewModels as it will get resolved by unity.